# Struggling to create a BST with characters from a string in a for loop

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

My goal is to create a binary search tree recursively with characters from a given string. Here is an example:

String: "^a^^!^dc^rb"

Here is what the BST should look like. (Every "^" is an internal node, and every char is a leaf.)

[image]

I understand what BSTs are and how they work. However, I am struggling as to how I can program a recursive solution.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public MsgTree(String encodingString) { //Constructor building the tree from a string
        root = null; //Automatically sets the root to null every time a new tree is made
        this.encodingString = encodingString;
        for(staticCharIdx = 0; staticCharIdx < encodingString.length(); staticCharIdx++) { //The for loop loops through every character in the string one char at a time
            char charToTest = encodingString.charAt(staticCharIdx); //The program creates a charToTest variable to use for creating the new MsgTree node.
            MsgTree newNode = new MsgTree(charToTest); //A new MsgTree node is created for every new char in the encodingString. It does this by calling the second MsgTree constructor
            if(staticCharIdx == 0) { //If the for loop is at the first char in the string, then it is considered to be the root of the MsgTree
                root = newNode;
            }           
            preOrderTraversal(newNode); //The program then calls a private function to perform a preOrder traversal of the tree
        }
    }
    
    public MsgTree(char payloadChar) { //Constructor for a single node with null children
        left = null; //This method assigns two children (left and right) to the char node and sets them both to null
        right = null;
        this.payloadChar = payloadChar; //A payloadChar value is utilized to avoid naming conflicts and for use in other methods
    } 
    
    private void preOrderTraversal(MsgTree newNode) { //This method performs a preOrder traversal of the string and creates it into a BST
        if(newNode == null) { //If the newNode taken from the constructor is null, then nothing happens. This happens when it is past the last char of the string.
            return;
        }
        preOrderTraversal(newNode.left); //Calls the same method, but focuses instead on the left child of the newNode
        System.out.printf("%s", newNode.payloadChar); //Prints the char value of the NewNode
        preOrderTraversal(newNode.right); //Calls the same method, but focuses instead on the right child of the newNode
    }
```

I can make the program work for the first 3 characters in the string, but I can't get more than that. I was thinking about using a "parent" value as the new "root" node, but I don't know exactly know how to implement that. I have thought about creating an iterative solution to set it up, but I've learned that it would take much longer to implement than using a for loop.

I would appreciate any help I can get. Thank you.

EDIT: I've changed my code to utilize switch statements instead of if, else statements to make it look cleaner and more efficient.

2ndEDIT: Ok, I think I have it figured out. However, I don't know if the for loop in the first constructor is necessary. Let me know your thoughts. Thanks for the help you have provided so far.

Comment: Create an iterative solution first,  then use the iterative solution as a model for the recursive solution.  Get something to work, then worry about refining it.

Comment: Where is the picture from? Is that a solution you worked out or is that given by the assignment?

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful. This is the example solution of the BST given by the assignment. NOTE: Creating the BST is only half of the assignment. I need to use the BST for the second half.